# Do shared dependencies between classloaders get loaded twice?

Tags: java, classloader

Let's say I have two classloaders, `x` and `y`, used for loading `ClassX` and `ClassY`, respectively, as well as their dependencies. Everything else in the application is loaded using the default classloaders.

Now assume that `ClassX` and `ClassY` share a dependency, `ClassZ`.

If the main application also has a dependency to `ClassZ` (whether or not it has actually loaded the class yet), my assumption is that `x`/`y` won't be used at all to resolve this as the default classloaders should be able to find it. (Please correct me if I'm wrong.)

Now, my main question is what happens if only `x` and `y` can locate `ClassZ`: If both `ClassX` and `ClassY` reference it, will it be loaded twice (i.e. waste twice as much space in PermGen) or is Java clever enough to detect that it's exactly the same class, loaded by two different classloaders, and just keep one copy in memory?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They will both have their own `Class` instance for `ClassZ`. Keeping such loading separate is important in various technologies built on Java, such as webservers or Java EE environments that may need to maintain separate contexts for deployed applications.

You are also correct in your assumption that if the parent classloader for `ClassX` and `ClassY` (assuming it is the same) has loaded `ClassZ`, then that one will be used by both its children. At least, that's the default approach. A classloader first delegates lookup to its parent and if that one can't find it, it will try itself. Some custom loaders may override this behaviour, though.

Complex classloader hierarchies can emerge. While this does "waste" some room in the permgen, trying to share resources is often more trouble than it's worth, and will cause compatibility issues or classloader leaks in some frameworks.

Comment: "if the parent classloader for `ClassX` and `ClassY` (assuming it is the same) has loaded `ClassZ`" Just to clarify, this still applies even if the parent classloader _hasn't_ loaded `ClassZ` yet, right?

Comment: @Smallhacker Correct. The children will ask their parent "do you have this class?" The parent may have it already, or may start looking for it through its resources (such as jars on its classpath). Also, if that parent can't find it, likely it will in turn ask its own parent. At the base lies the bootstrap classloader, which loads the core Java libraries.

Comment: A nice technique with classloaders is a delegation-classloader as parent. Here you need not to have a single parent class loader but can have "many" parents at the same time through the delegation strategy used, which may change dynamically too if needed. This approach keeps the "parent-first classloading mechanism" up and may provide a cleaner separation of classes that (hardly) can't be unloaded (Singletons and Enums). If a singleton does not hold a strong reference to other classes (not in the singletons CL) it is possible to unload parts of the classes + CL and reduce memory footprint.